# How to write logs to files of size 64KB in C++/VC++?

Tags: c++, logging, file-io, visual-c++

How to write logs to files of size 64KB(to allow notepad to read).Once the file has reached 64KB it should go head and create another , another ......
File names can be automatically generated.

I tried the following code

```
static int iCounter=1;
CString temp;
      static CStdioFile f(L"c:\\Log1.txt", CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeRead |  CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeNoTruncate);

 int nlength = (int)f.GetLength();
 if(nlength>(nMaxFileSize*1024))
 {
     //need to create a new file
     f.Close();
     iCounter++;
     temp.Format(_T("%s%d%s"), "c:\\Log",iCounter, ".txt");
     f.Open(temp,CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeRead | CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeNoTruncate);

 }
 f.SeekToEnd();
 f.WriteString(str);
 f.WriteString(L"\r\n");
```

i am looking for a better alternative.

Comment: I was trying with GetLength() function that gets me file size on disk looking for better alternative.

Comment: Where did you come up with the 64KB limit from? I use notepad to open much larger files all the time. It's a crappy text editor, but you should have no problem opening files as large as a few MB. Or, better yet, start using one of the many free editors available and are much better than notepad.

Comment: Try measuring the length of your strings, rathar than the length of the file, or measure it after flushing - some of your changes are not written to the files.

@eran very true, notepad++ is my choice but many other exist.

Comment: @eran - but at some point you might want to limit your log file sizes - if not 64KB, then maybe several hundred MB or 2GB.  Regardless it's the same problem, just with a different frequency.

Answer (score 5):

Write a wrapper class that accepts log strings, writes them to the current log file and keeps a total-string-length counter.

When it reaches your threshold, close the current log file, create a new one, and reset your counter.

You can use a numbering name scheme, like `log00001.txt, log 00002.txt, ...`.

Comment: Sometimes a solution is this easy :)

Answer (score 3):

Use log4cplus which certainly can handle it - being properly configured.

See http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Where can I find the documentation for logging into file as mentioned in question?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/Log4cplus.aspx this may do the job, after that search for "log4cplus log rotation" - you'll find lots of useful stuff.